# Regex to get each item in an xpath-like string, with each subscript as a group

Tags: regex, grouping

I'd like to take an xpath-like string such as:

```
a.b.c[2].d[123].e1[4].f88[5]
```

And have each path-part as a match, with each subscript ("array index") as a group, like this:

```
match 1: a
match 2: b
match 3: c, group 1: 123
match 4: e1, group 1: 4,
match 5: f88, group 1: 5
```

I tried with the following (which doesn't work):

```
[^.]+(?:\[)*([0-9]+)*(?:\])*
```

As I understand this Regex, it means:

1. First, match all characters except for a dot
2. Then, check (but don't capture) for a left square bracket - it may be present 0 to unlimited times.
3. Then, check for any number, with length 1 to unlimited - and capture as a group.
4. Then, do 2 again for a right square brack.

But it doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

Comment: How about this?  `(?<=^|\.)([^\.\[\s]*)(?:\[(.*?)\])?`  https://regex101.com/r/ea6Kb8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^.]+(?:\[)*([0-9]+)*(?:\])*`

*"But it doesn't work"* because `+` is *greedy* and *consumes* all the characters before the dot. Furthermore, each subscript is integrally optional, rather than part by part.

Applying those criteria, this expression does work:

`([^.\[]+)(?:\[(\d+)\])?`

[Regex101 Test](https://regex101.com/r/y6B3sS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried:

- The pattern that you tried matches too much, as the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^.]+` matches 1 or more times any char except a dot, and can also match square brackets.
- Note that this notation `(?:\[)*` is the same as `\[*` and matches 0 or more times an opening square bracket

If the `\G` anchor [is supported](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G), and you want to match the example string only from the start of the string, you might use 2 capture groups for the data that you want, and match the dots and square brackets in between.

```
\G([^\][.\s]+)(?:\[(\d+)\])?\.?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, or at the start of the string
- `([^\][.\s]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ char other than `]` `[` `.` or a whitespace char (as there do not seem to be any spaces in the example string)
- `(?:\[(\d+)\])?` Optionally match capture **group 2** between matching square brackets
- `\.?` Match an optional dot to continue the consecutive matching for the `\G` anchor

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CyjBnh/1)

If there can not be a dot at the end of the string, and there must be at least 1 dot present, you can assert the whole format first from the start of the string:

```
(?:^(?=[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)+$)|\G(?!^))\.?([^\][.]+)(?:\[(\d+)\])?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BQ7L4w/1)